# Does Wordpress lock tables during post & post meta insert/update/delete?

Tags: mysql, performance, wordpress

I have a script that updates 3,000 Wordpress posts nightly (Real Estate CMS).  When the script is running, the website won't load at all.

**Does Wordpress lock tables during the update or is it just a performance issue?**

Any recomendations on how to improve this process?

**The script uses the following functions:**

```
wp_insert_post
get_post_custom
update_post_meta
delete_post_meta
wp_set_object_terms
get_object_taxonomies
```

Comment: You mean if they do a transaction

Comment: I mean that while the import is running, the rest of the website will not load. Once the import is completed the website loads immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue wasn't with Wordpress, but that I has PHP Sessions enabled and once I turned off sessions the problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

You still have no response so i'm gonna give a try:

You should look at your script if you're performing a MYSQL transaction during this update then the tables could be locked.

If it's not a transaction that's a performance issue:

Proposition to solve it:
To solve it you should not update all your database in one time and do a x amount of queries then reload the php page and doing and x amount of queries again until the update is fully done.